# ros2 message documentation?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dumb question... where's the ROS2 equivalent of http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/CameraInfo.html?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/311100/ros2-message-documentation?/) by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1247 on 2018-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That doesn't exist yet. We haven't gotten automated code documentation generation running yet, and the pretty html version of the messages is part of that.

Until then you'll need to just look at the files directly, e.g.:

https://github.com/ros2/common_interfaces/blob/master/sensor_msgs/msg/CameraInfo.msg

There's also the local command `ros2 msg show sensor_msgs/CameraInfo`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2018-12-19**:
Terrific, thanks for the quick and thorough response.